# Visual Objects - Retrieving string DEFINE dynamically - #ifdef is returning false

Tags: clipper

This is regarding the [Visual Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Objects) programming language based upon [Clipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipper_(programming_language)).

I'm trying to load the values of a few `DEFINE` constants, I've tried using `#ifdef` to determine if they exist however it doesn't seem to work with strings, just numbers or logics, e.g.:

```
DEFINE TEST_LOGIC := True
DEFINE TEST_NUM := 1
DEFINE TEST_STRING := "HELLO"

#IFDEF TEST_LOGIC
  // Runs
#ENDIF
#IFDEF TEST_NUM
  // Runs
#ENDIF
#IFDEF TEST_STRING
  // Does not run
#ENDIF
```

Is there some other way of determining whether they exist and returning their values? I've tried `VarGet()` and `MemVarGet()` but they can't see the constant and cause a runtime error, and `#ifdef` cannot accept a method call like `!Empty(TEST_STRING)` (will not compile), using a direct comparison like `#ifdef TEST_STRING > " "` also doesn't work (compiles and runs but the code block does not execute).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this using `DEFINE` statements containing strings, however if it's changed to a `GLOBAL` declaration then the `#ifdef` statement will work as expected.